# adding different text to multiple grids in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap, geom-text

Using the built-in iris database, I am trying to add the Pearson correlation for the relationship be Sepal length and Sepal width by species on a faceted scatter plot. How can I tell R to enter each value into each plot?

I was able to solve the problem by entering the R values manually using the following code.

```
z<- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(Pearson.Corr= round(cor(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, method = "pearson"),digits = 2))
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ Species, scales="free_x") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "black") +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=rel(0.5), color="white"), strip.background = element_rect(fill="royalblue")) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplots of Petal Length Versus Width across Iris Species with linear regression", X= "Petal Length", Y = "Petal Width") +
  geom_text(data=z, mapping= aes(label= c("R=", "R=", "R="), cyl= Species, x= c(1.5, 4, 5.5), y = c(1, 2, 1.25)))
```

Is there a way to improve the code?

Comment: Your code uses petals, not sepals as written in the question ?

Comment: You are right. However, the code is correct. I mistakenly wrote Sepal in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat_cor()` from the [ggpubr](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_cor.html) package. The default is Pearson.

Example using values for Petal, as in your example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  facet_wrap(~Species) + 
  stat_cor()
```

Result:

[image]

Here's another approach - add the label to the facet title:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Pearson.Corr= paste(Species, "R = ", 
                             round(cor(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, 
                                   method = "pearson"), digits = 2))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~Pearson.Corr)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. That helps. However, just for the purpose of learning, How can I insert a label that is half repeated text like here "R=" and half equation cor with a different solution for every grid?

Comment: If it were me I'd be tempted to create a new variable with the label and add it to the facet title. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've got is almost there. In the `geom_text()` aesthetic, you can use `paste()` to add the correlation values as part of the `label` argument.

```
z<- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(Pearson.Corr= round(cor(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, method = "pearson") ,digits = 2))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ Species, scales="free_x") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "black") +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=rel(0.5), color="white"), strip.background = element_rect(fill="royalblue")) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplots of Petal Length Versus Width across Iris Species with linear regression", X= "Petal Length", Y = "Petal Width") +
  geom_text(data=z, mapping = aes(label= paste("R =", z$Pearson.Corr), x= -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 0, vjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
z<- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(Pearson.Corr= round(cor(Petal.Length,     Petal.Width, method = "pearson"),digits = 2))
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ Species, scales="free_x") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "black") +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=rel(0.5), color="white"),     strip.background = element_rect(fill="royalblue")) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplots of Petal Length Versus Width across Iris Species with   linear regression", X= "Petal Length", Y = "Petal Width") +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = c(1, 3, 4.5), label.y = c(1, 2, 1.25))
```

[image]